# String isn't getting mutated after using a function, despite being mutated inside the function c language

Tags: c, string, pointers, scope, mutation

Quick summary - I am testing my functions, and for that, I've decided to write my own add_as_first() and add_as_last() functions, which are adding character to the old string array, through creating a new one and making a copy, without using default c language string functions. And for some reason, one out of two string arrays isn't behaving like I would like it to do. I've added strlen() function for debugging and I can see that inside a print_file function my string array is perfectly healthy and growing bigger as the function goes through its cycles. But for some reason, when the function ends, one of the string "res" is back to 0 length, while, the second string, "body", got properly mutated and has a value which is supposed to have. The difference between them is that "res" is getting filled by using add_as_last() function inside a print_file loop function, while, "body" is getting filled by using add_as_first() function inside a forming_list() function, which is inside print_file(). Any idea why it behaves this way? It looks like scoping issues but it should work properly, considering that both "body" and "res" are being used in about the same way.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h>

#define x_size 4
#define y_size 4


char* add_as_first(char *given_arr, char given_char, int check) {
    int strLen = 0;
    while (given_arr[strLen] != '\0') {
        strLen++;
    }
    char *new_arr;
    new_arr = (char*)malloc((strLen + 1 + 1) * sizeof(char));
    
    new_arr[0] = given_char;
    int i = 0;

    for (; i < strLen; i++) {
        new_arr[i + 1] = given_arr[i]; 
    }
    new_arr[i + 1] = '\0';
    if ((i + 1 + 1) != (strLen + 1 + 1)) {
        printf("WE GOT A MEMORY LEAK OUT THERE\n");
    }

    if (check != 0) {
        free(given_arr);
    }
    return new_arr;
}

char* add_as_last(char *given_arr, char given_char, int check) {
    int strLen = 0; 
    while (given_arr[strLen] != '\0') {
        strLen++;
    }
    char* newString = (char*)malloc((strLen + 1 + 1) * sizeof(char));
    int i = 0;

    for(; i < strLen; i++) {
        newString[i] = given_arr[i];
            
    }

    newString[i] = given_char;
    newString[i + 1] = '\0';
    if ((i + 1 + 1) != (strLen + 1 + 1)) {
        printf("WE GOT A MEMORY LEAK OUT THERE\n");
    }
    return newString;
}

void forming_list(int file_arr[][y_size], int i, int j, char body[]) {
    char thing = '0';
    thing = j + '0';
    body = add_as_first(body, thing, 1);
    body = add_as_first(body, ',', 1);
    thing = i + '0';
    body = add_as_first(body, thing, 1);
    body = add_as_first(body, ' ', 1);
    if ((file_arr[i][j] == 1) || (file_arr[i][j] == 5)) {
        if (j < x_size - 1) {
            forming_list(file_arr, i, j + 1, body);
        } else {
            forming_list(file_arr, i + 1, 0, body);
        }
    } else if ((file_arr[i][j] == 2) || (file_arr[i][j] == 6)) {
        if (j != 0) {
            forming_list(file_arr, i, j - 1, body);
        } else {
            forming_list(file_arr, i - 1, x_size - 1, body);
        } 
    } else if ((file_arr[i][j] == 3) || (file_arr[i][j] == 7)) {
        if (i == 0) {
            forming_list(file_arr, y_size - 1, j, body);
        } else {
            forming_list(file_arr, i - 1, j, body);
        } 
    } else if ((file_arr[i][j] == 4) || (file_arr[i][j] == 8)) {
        if (i == y_size - 1) {
            forming_list(file_arr, 0, j, body);
        } else {
            forming_list(file_arr, i + 1, j, body);
        } 
    } 
}

void print_file(int file_arr[][y_size], char *res, char *body) {
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    for(i; i < y_size; i++) {
        for (j; j < x_size; j++) {
            if ((file_arr[i][j] >= 5) && (file_arr[i][j] <= 9)) {
                res = add_as_last(res, '#', 1);
            } 
            else if ((file_arr[i][j] >= 1) && (file_arr[i][j] <= 4)) {
                res = add_as_last(res, '#', 1);
                forming_list(file_arr, i, j, body); 
            } else {
                res = add_as_last(res, 'x', 1);
            }
        }
        res = add_as_last(res, '\n', 1);
        printf("Length of string = %zu \n",strlen(res));
        j = 0;
    }
}

int main()
{

    int disp[x_size][y_size] = {
    {0, 1, 8, 0},
    {0, 0, 8, 0},
    {0, 9, 6, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0}
};
    char *res;
    char *body;
    res = (char*)malloc((1) * sizeof(char));
    body = (char*)malloc((1) * sizeof(char));

    res[0] = '\0';
    body[0] = '\0';
    printf("Length of string = %zu \n",strlen(res));
    print_file(disp, res, body);
    printf("Length of string = %zu \n",strlen(res));
    printf("%s\n", res);
    printf("%s\n", body);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

> Length of string = 0  //After creating a res line

> Length of string = 5  //After the first outer for loop

> Length of string = 10 //After the second outer for loop

> Length of string = 15 //After the third outer for loop

> Length of string = 20 //After the fourth outer for loop just before exiting function

> Length of string = 0  //Outside the function before printing "res" string

> ```
>                   //Printing empty "res" string
> ```

> 2,1 2,2 1,2 0,2 0,1  //Printing properly filled "body" string

Why "body" and "res" value is so different after my program is finished working, despite being so similar?

Comment: Remember thar function arguments are passed *by value*. That is, the value of the argument is *copied* into the functions argument variable. Modifying this copy will of course not modify the original. Think about that for the call `print_file(disp, res, body)`. And do some research about *emulating pass by reference in C*.

Comment: I know about pass by reference/pass by value difference, and I understand that I could just return the "res" and it would work fine, but I am trying to understand the difference, why "body" is working as intended, and "res" is lost in the memory?

Comment: You very likely have some kind of undefined behavior in your code. Try to scale back your program (a lot!), take the *minimal* part of your [mcve] to its extreme. Make sure it works. Then add one small part at a time, building (with verbose extra warnings enabled) and testning. When the problem occurs you can narrow it down and debug only the small non-working bit.

Comment: Also please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Your question is a wall of text that is very hard to read.

Comment: I know that I should avoid asking repeatable questions, but my issue is that I don't know how to formulate it. If I would be more familiar with these shenanigans and terms in C I think I wouldn't bother creating annoying questions.

Answer (score 2):

Your `print_file` function is modifying `res`, but the new pointer never gets passed back into main.
So main has its `res` still pointing to the (long destroyed) original `res`, which produces undefined bahavior for `strlen` (or anything else).

You should pass the `res` pointer by reference or pass the pointer to it, so the modification gets back into main.

Comment: I thought this way, but why then a pointer to "body" is not destroyed and working properly?

Comment: @Jermog — undefined behaviour is nasty. It doesn't have to break.  It doesn't have to work.  It doesn't have to make sense.  It doesn't have to be consistent.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler So, my "body" pointer is as much compromised as "res", I am just lucky (or even unlucky for not understanding the real cause) that it works and I should make sure that both "res" and "body" pointers are returned in some way or another?

Comment: `body` is destroyed. If you run it through a static analyzer, you'll even get a warning at line 100 (`forming_list(file_arr, i, j, body)`) that this uses memory after free.

Comment: It's not just a matter of returning the pointers. Your call to `free` at line 29 is mismanagement of memory. `add_as_first` doesn't own that memory. You need to rethink how you handle memory through this whole program.

Comment: @RobNapier Can you recommend a static analyzer that you use, which helps with debugging purposes? I am fairly new with C and dived into that language mainly to learn the shenanigans with memory and pointers.

Comment: `clang --analyze`

Comment: Thanks, gonna use it from now on.

Comment: I wish I had a good resource to point you to for learning C; I'm old enough that I learned it by reading the K&R Book (you probably shouldn't learn C that way; that was a long time ago). But I do recommend you sit down with a course or book to learn C memory management. Looking at this code, it feels like your background is in languages with more automatic memory management. Your definitions of `res` and `body` as 1-element `malloc` blocks is a very unnatural approach for C.

Comment: Your reimplementation of basic string functions, however, is a great way to get started. A good "dive-in" approach might be to look at the headers for string.h, try to write your own versions, and then compare to the FreeBSD implementations: https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/tree/master/lib/libc/string. Some of them are over-complicated for basic C work, but definitely the headers will give you a better idea of how C functions are expected to work.

Comment: Thanks for the Github link, going to check it out. Yes, overall this behavior felt wrong when I was implementing it, but the whole point of these functions are just taken out from the bigger project, as they are newly written addition, to test them separately, before trying out to make them work as a part of a bigger program, trying to emulate their behavior as best as possible.

Comment: I suggest 
K N King
[C Programming: A Modern Approach, 2nd Edn](https://smile.amazon.com/dp/0393979504/) 2008 as a decent relatively modern C book in preference to K&R 2nd Edn these days.   Also consider 
Jens Gustedt
[Modern C](https://smile.amazon.com/dp/1617295817) 2020 — aka
[Modern C](https://www.manning.com/books/modern-c) — but it isn't as easy a read as King's book.